# Do C# 8 default interface implementations allow for multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/, one of the new features coming in C# 8 is the default implementation of interfaces. Will this new feature also implicitly allow for multiple inheritance? If not, what exactly will happen if I try the following:

```
public interface A { int Foo() => 1; }
public interface B { int Foo() => 2; }
public class C : A, B { }
```

Comment: There is no reason to expect that it wouldn't work. Read the link again, focussing on `The above code will produce the compile-time error: AnyClass does not contain a member DefaultMethod.`. This seems to indicate that something akin to explicit interface implementation is used. Also see https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/25/proposed-default-interface-methods-in-c-8/ .

Comment: As I know, you can point parent explicit: `A.Foo()` and `B.Foo()`.

Comment: You can implement more than 1 interface

Comment: @Rahul that's not the point. The question is: if two interfaces implement a method with the same signature, and a class implements both those interfaces, which method will win and why?

Comment: @CodeCaster `A` will win if the variable is of type `A`. `B` will win if the variable is of type `B`.

Comment: @mjwills that's in the case of explicit interface implementations. Question is, what if the variable is of type `C`, will you be able to call `C.Foo()`, and which implementation will that call, or will it fail to compile because `C.Foo()` doesn't exist, or because no best overload can be matched?

Comment: Check the link I provided @CodeCaster and the one provided by the OP . No, you can't call `C.Foo` as per my earlier comment. Now, your answer raises a great question (what if there is a **third** interface that 'inherits' the two of them?) - which is a great question, but a slightly different one.

Comment: And now I realise my earlier link was the wrong one. https://www.infoq.com/articles/default-interface-methods-cs8 is the one I meant. My apologies.

Comment: @mjwills I think you do have a point, the specs say _"Note that a class does not inherit members from its interfaces; that is not changed by this feature"_. It's as if the method implemented in the interface does not "live" in the class at all.

Comment: @CodeCaster That is what I meant by `This seems to indicate that something akin to explicit interface implementation is used.`

Comment: @mjwills good point, I'd love to, but given a spec nor an implementation is complete there's nowhere I can validate my suspicions. There's only https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoATEANQAfAAIAGAAQiAjAG4AsACgRAZikAmCQGEJICQQCC3fQCEJAbyUTrUtSIAsEgLIAKAJQWrN7y5eG3MAAWbMhuAHQAYhwc7gqK3gC+SkmKSqoSbCRklBD6BkqW8TaZMBJRMW5e1oXe3iIA7BJyVRIpKWlqJdlQVKYFLSVl0e4tNbXWDRLqcYnJSh0ZWeQ9uQQ6eobGBCb9iglAA=, but I'm not sure how authoritative that is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Credit to @CodeCaster for his/her great comments that prompted this answer.*

The [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.md) states:

> Note that a class does not inherit members from its interfaces; that
>   is not changed by this feature:

Thus, it seems reasonable (although impossible to confirm with 100% certainty until it is shipped) that:

```
public interface A { int Foo() => return 1; }
public interface B { int Foo() => return 2; }
public class C : A, B { }
```

will work fine.

Just as the proposal shows:

```
new C().M(); // error: class 'C' does not contain a member 'M'
```

then we can assume, your version:

```
new C().Foo();
```

will also not compile.

The proposal shows:

```
IA i = new C();
i.M();
```

as valid, which is equivalent to your:

```
A i = new C();
i.Foo();
```

Since `i` is declared as type `A` there is no reason to assume the same would not work if `A` was changed to `B` - there are no collisions to speak of.

The entire point of this feature is to allow interfaces to be extended in a safe way (see [this video](https://youtu.be/QZ0rWLaMZeI?t=4160)). If this **only** worked if you implemented one interface, that seems contrary to the objective of the feature. And given the feature appears to be implemented in a way *roughly* akin to explicit interface implementation (which is why we can't invoke `C.Foo()` directly), I think we can *reasonably* assume that it will most likely allow for multiple interface implementation.

Answer (score 28):

Your question is answered by Mads Torgersen in the blog post you linked to:

> Actually interfaces are still quite far from abstract classes. Classes don’t inherit members from interfaces, so if a class leaves a member M implemented by the interface, the class does not have a member M! It’s like an explicit implementation today; you have to convert to the interface in order to get at such members.

So with your example:

```
public interface A { int Foo() => 1; }
public interface B { int Foo() => 2; }
public class C : A, B { }
```

You cannot do this:

```
var something = new C();
var x = something.Foo(); /* does not compile */
```

You can do the following:

```
var something = new C();
var x = ((A)something).Foo(); /* calls the implementation provided by A */
var y = ((B)something).Foo(); /* calls the implementation provided by B */
```